# Configuring Bamboo to use MS Build Xaml Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, bamboo

My Project is slowly moving away from TFS and going over to Git and to Bamboo.

However, the project uses xaml files to direct how the builds work, run unit tests before building msi, etc.

What I am trying to figure out is how I can configure Bamboo to point to this solution in the same way it is done now. Has anyone have any experience of this and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The XAML part of the TFS build is proprietary and will only work with TFS.

You'll need to recreate the build definitions in Bamboo as plans and then add the specific tasks you need to compile, test and package.